# How to view the errors from all buffers?

Tags: flycheck

Is it possible to view all errors?

`flycheck-list-errors` only show errors for current buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not possible, and we do not plan to add this feature to Flycheck itself.  We think that it is beyond Flycheck's scope, and we believe that it's the task of a build system or a CI to provide an overview over the entire "project".

---

I'm sorry but you have to write this feature yourself.  You would add a hook for `flycheck-mode`, which in turn adds a local hook to `flycheck-after-syntax-check-hook`.  In this local you you would simply collect all `flycheck-errors` of the current buffer, and add them to a buffer in Tabulated List Mode.